# How to apply a StructType to a dataframe that is receiving data from a Kafka topic?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I am writing data into a Kafka topic using Spark as below.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType, DecimalType, TimestampType, DateType


publish_final_df = spark.read.parquet("s3://some_s3_file_path")
final_df = publish_final_df.select(F.to_json(F.struct(F.col("*"))).alias("value"))
```

## WRITE TO TOPIC

```
final_df.write.format("kafka")\
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_broker)\
        .option("acks", "1")\
        .option("kafka.compression.type", "snappy")\
        .option("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_SSL")\
        .option("kafka.sasl.jaas.config", oauth_config)\
        .option("kafka.sasl.login.callback.handler.class", "io.strimzi.kafka.oauth.client.JaasClientOauthLoginCallbackHandler")\
        .option("kafka.sasl.mechanism", "OAUTHBEARER")\
        .option("topic", 'topic_a')\
        .save()
```

The above step runs successfully. To read the data from the same topic: `topic_a` I prepared a schema as below which resembles `final_df`

```
data_struct = StructType([StructField("col1", StringType()),
                               StructField("col2", TimestampType()),
                               StructField("col3", IntegerType())
                               ])
```

While reading data from the same topic: `topic_a`, I am trying to apply the above structtype: `data_struct` and read as below.

## READ FROM TOPIC

```
initial_df = spark.readStream.format("kafka")\
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_broker)\
    .option("retries", 3)\
    .option("acks", "1")\
    .option("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_SSL")\
    .option("kafka.sasl.jaas.config", oauth_config)\
    .option("kafka.sasl.login.callback.handler.class", "io.strimzi.kafka.oauth.client.JaasClientOauthLoginCallbackHandler")\
    .option("kafka.sasl.mechanism", "OAUTHBEARER")\
    .option("subscribe", 'topic_a')\
    .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")\
    .load()\
    .select(from_json(col('value'), data_struct).alias('band')) \
    .selectExpr("band.col1 as col1, band.col2 as col2, band.col3 as col3 *")
initial_df.writeStream.format('console').outputMode('append').start().awaitTermination()
```

When I run the above code I see an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1287.select.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'jsontostructs(`value`)' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires string type, however, '`value`' is of binary type.;;
'Project [jsontostructs(StructField(col1,StringType,true), StructField(col2,IntegerType,true), StructField(col3,IntegerType,true) AS band#883]
```

I am coming from Scala to Python and the code:

```
.select(from_json(col('value'), data_struct).as('band')) \
.selectExpr("band.col1 as col1, band.col2 as col2, band.col3 as col3 *")
```

is working properly in Scala and I applied the same in Python and it is failing. Could anyone let me know what is the mistake I did here and how can I correct it ?

Comment: Please show an example JSON record that is in your topic

Comment: Also, you need to first cast the value column to a string before you can use `from_json` on it, as the error says `argument 1 requires string type, however, 'value' is of binary type`

Comment: @OneCricketeer I have posted the answer. I had to deserialise the JSON object and then apply the structtype on top of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake was not converting the Json to string before applying the StrucType to it. Below line solved my issue.

```
select(from_json(col('value').cast('string'), data_struct).alias("json_dta")).selectExpr('json_dta.*')
```